# What does this blue asterisk/star indicate on top of an NPC?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've just informed the blacksmith that his apprentice is dead, and now he's got an odd icon over his head:

[image]

It looks like a blue asterisk or some kind of star.  What does this symbol indicate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means they have information for you.  If you click on them and select *talk*, it should provide you new options you haven't seen before (not grayed out).

Comment: Additionally, while the asterisk means they have new conversation, not all conversation will produce an asterisk.

Answer (score 6):

It means they have a new dialog or conversation that you can initiate.  New topics will be in white text, and ones that you have already heard will be in grey.

Comment: Easy 'cheevos if you listen to everybody in all the acts

Comment: @NickT Either I missed someone, or it was another achievement I lost due to the server problems (I currently have credit for Nightmare boss achievements while missing the normal versions, for example).