# Why does my Artisan have a silver * over his head?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this blue asterisk/star indicate on top of an NPC?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66673/what-does-this-blue-asterisk-star-indicate-on-top-of-an-npc)

The title says it all. My artisan has a silver Asterix floating above his head, and I can't figure out what it means or why it's there.

[image: Whats this?]

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Yep its a dupe. I searched before I posted too, but for Artisan questions, as I didn't know the star appeared above other NPCS. Blast. VTC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This simply means he has something *new* to say. Just click on him, then choose Talk. At least one of the conversation topics should be highlighted.

This doesn't just apply to him though. Every NPC that has something to say gets this from time to time, even your followers.

Comment: Wait, your saying in addition to feeding this idiot all my hard-earned magical loot AND paying him my hard-earned coin, just so he can MAYBE give me something worthwhile in return, I also have to TALK to the guy? Screw this game. -.-

Comment: @Ender you don't _have_ to, it just adds some informations to the story

Comment: @Kappei I know, it was a joke :)

Comment: @Ender Oh, ok :P sorry, I've seen too many gamers angering and arguing about even stupider matters... And reading sarcasm in a typed text is really hard :)